# After restoring .exe file from Avira Security Isolation, lnk1104 happens and cannot delete .exe file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, antivirus

I built a C++ visual studio project for homework3 prob2 so I name it "HW3 Q2 cmp".

But I make a mistake about vector size in the beginning. But after a few failures. The avira security somehow put my .exe file to isolation. I looked into it and restore it from isolation.

But then the nightmare error LNK1104 happened.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\Users\Pun Wing Hon\Desktop\Cityu\Year Three\EE2331 data struct\HW3 Q2 cmp\x64\Debug\HW3 Q2 cmp.exe'    HW3 Q2 cmp  C:\Users\Pun Wing Hon\Desktop\Cityu\Year Three\EE2331 data struct\HW3 Q2 cmp\HW3 Q2 cmp\LINK    1

Then I use GDB online to fix the code. After fixing the code and tested it in another vs project. Then I fix the problems in the origin "HW3 Q2 cmp" until "No issues found". But the LNK1104 still there.

What is more scary is when I want to delete the project manually(delete the whole project file in window explorer). It cannot delete the .exe file and asked for administrator while I myself is the administrator of the computer.

I checked the task manager and no thread is running. The properties show that I, or all users should have the complete control of the file and can delete the file.

I changed my account from microsoft to computer But still not work.

Comment: Did you try running VS as administrator? (right click on visual studio and select mode)

Comment: No. Just tried. Lnk 1104 still there .

Comment: get rid of avira - windows built-in av is perfectly adequete